# delphi 2007 command line compiler dcc32.cfg problem

Tags: delphi

I'm using the command line compiler for builds.  One problem I see is that the paths mentioned there seem to need to be the short versions of the filenames such that they don't contain any spaces.  I don't know so much about this even though I have used it for some time.

I recently upgraded to d2009 and the problem started then.

Is there a way around shortening the path?

I should say I'm not eager to change to use the MS Build tool at this time.  I just want to build an old copy of my app & get back to other work.

Here's the path used in the `dcc32.cfg` file for the `-I`, `-U`, `-O`, and `-R` parameters:

```
$(BDS)\LIB;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\BDS\4.0\RAVERE~1\Lib;c:\prj\lib\lib2002;C:\DOCUME~1\ALLUSE~1\DOCUME~1\RADSTU~1\5.0\Bpl;c:\DOCUME~1\mike\MYDOCU~1\BORLAN~1\bpl;C:\Prj\Lib\LOCKBO~1\source;C:\Prj\Lib\MyComp;C:\Prj\Lib\ABBREV~1\source;C:\Prj\Lib\ZLib;C:\Prj\Lib\MinMod;C:\Prj\Lib\HELPMA~1;C:\Prj\Lib\DXGETT~1;c:\windows\system32;c:\prj\lib\xpburn;C:\Prj\Lib\WININE~1;C:\Prj\Lib\regexpr\Source;C:\Prj\Lib\VCARDR~1;C:\PROGRA~1\Raize\RC4\Lib\BDS2006;C:\Prj\Lib\jcl\lib\d10;C:\Prj\Lib\jcl\source;C:\Prj\Lib\jvcl\lib\D10;C:\Prj\Lib\jvcl\common;C:\Prj\Lib\jvcl\RESOUR~1;C:\Prj\Lib\ProE6\Delphi;C:\Prj\Lib\FastMM4;C:\Prj\Lib\OPENOF~1;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\Library\Delphi11;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX38D9~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXBD88~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\XPTHEM~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX2EBC~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXC5FB~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX7C7C~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXPRES~3\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXPRES~4\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXC73B~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX7165~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXPRES~2\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EXPRES~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX749C~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\DEVELO~1\EX0A1A~1\Sources;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\madBasic\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\MADDIS~1\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\MADEXC~1\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\MADKER~1\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\MADSEC~1\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\madShell\BDS4;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\madShell\DeXter;C:\Prj\Lib\Mad\madExcept\..\Plugins;
```

I've copied it from the IDE's path like I have done in the path and used a program to shorten the path names.

Although there are no spaces in that path, it still can't find indy's `IdCoder.dcu` at `C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\Indy10`

According to the d2007 environment variables, `$(BDS)` would apparently expand to `c:\program files\codegear\rad studio\5.0`

The IDE is considering this library path to be valid.

Why is this happening?  I bet it's a simple mistake I haven't thought of!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show us the -U part of the dcc32.cfg in full, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to put the paths in quotes, that's the standard way of handling path-/filenames with spaces in Windows, though I never tried that in Delphi DCUs.

So, instead of

```
$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10
```

try

```
"$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10"
```

You could also try

```
"C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\Indy10"
```

to check if the environment variable is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you have to put the whole directory list into quotes, like in Vladimir's example, but I guess the problem really is somewhere else...

Comment: at some point after the quotes it started working.  not sure what else was wrong but it works now.  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Although .cfg files do still work in the Delphi 2007 command line compiler, you should really be using MSBuild to compile your projects. CFG files are not used by the IDE anymore. Any compiler options you set design time do not get written to the .cfg file. Using MSBuild is not harder then using .cfg. And if you want it is even more flexible since you can change the actual build processes.

msbuild YourProject.dproj

Comment: i should move forward to MS Build at some point soon.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi actually will give you the command line needed in the output tab when you do a compile or build.

1. Build your project normally in Delphi.
2. At the bottom there will be a tab called "Output", Look for a line that says "Target CoreCompile" (in D2007 - may be different in other versions).  The line below that will be the command line used to build your project (This is what you want).  Btw - you do not have to wait for your project to complete building, you can hit cancel before it finishes because all you need is that DCC32 command line call.  Also, if you had done previous compiles you may want to right click and clear the output before building so you do not have a lot of "noise".
3. Click on that line to highlight it, then right click the line and choose copy.
4. Open an empty batch file and paste.  (warning,the line may be very long)
5. Now, go to the start of that line and if your path to the DCC32 compiler includes a space, then you will need to put quotes around the DCC32 call, don't put the quotes around the parameters.
6. Insert a line above the DCC32 call and enter dos commands to set the directory to the directory where your dpr file is, otherwise DCC32 will say it cannot find your project.  For example.
   `G:`
   then
   `cd \Apps\MyProject`
7. Save the batch file and you are ready to go.

Comment: +1 for promoting good old dcc32.exe - easy to set up on build servers too

Answer (score 1):

Is the $(BDS) environment variable set when you're compiling the program from the command-line? If not, that might be the problem.

Putting quotes around paths containing spaces will likely solve the problem with spaces. This has worked for me:

-U"C:\Path to libraries\First library;C:\Path to libraries\Second library;C:\Path to libraries\Third library"

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have *applicationname*.cfg file in the current folder. Dcc32 will try to read configuration from that file first. Only if the file does not exist will it read from dcc32.cfg.

Comment: Not true. dcc32.cfg will still be read. The difference is which takes precendence... If an options is set in both cfg files, applicationname.cfg overrides the dcc32.cfg setting. If an option has multiple values (e.g. search paths), then paths in applicationname.cfg will be searched first. In a similar way, command-line options take precedence over applicationname.cfg options. Also note, the command-line option --no-config can be used to ignore cfg files altogether.